# Jenkins Kubernetes plugin for Selenium - Maven pulls the dependencies but cannot compile

Tags: selenium, jenkins, kubernetes

I've adapted the following example from the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/selenium.groovy)

I've created a simple Jenkins pipeline job and added the [groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/selenium.groovy) script in line. Maven pulls all the dependencies, but weirdly fails at the compilation step.

[Here's the console output](https://gist.github.com/batchu/0051b38e169e8a8c788850b4ea015f8e)

How does one go about even debugging this as the failure happens on a temporary container?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the settings.xml. It had a windows path which messed up maven's classpath. I added a line "sleep 99m" to keep the container on hold and then I SSH'd in to the container to debug to identify the root cause.